# 指標を定めてコミュニティでの取り組みによる効果を測定しましょう

Tags: 討議

翻訳をしてくれた[@Sieg](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/7676/sieg)に感謝します。

---

[私たちのコミュニティの目標](/help/manifesto)は、検索エンジンにキーワードを入力することで、日本語で詳細に書かれた回答へのリンクが検索結果に表示される環境を整えることです。

この目標を実現するために、私たちは一緒に日本語コミュニティでオープンな知識ベースを構築しています。壮大な目標への道のりは曲がりくねった険しいもので、途中で道を見失ってしまう可能性があります。正しい道から逸れてしまわないように目印が必要なのではないでしょうか。

> どのようなコミュニティの指標が私たちをゴールへ導いてくれるのかを考えてみましょう。

[image]

#### 指標を選択する際に考慮すべきこと

利用可能な任意のデータを用いて指標を定めることができますが、既存の指標にこだわる必要はありません。他方で言及することに価値があります。:

- 使用する指標が少なければ少ないほどよいでしょう。 全体的な進展を確認するための指標を1つだけ作成できれば最良ですが、一方、システムには一緒に測定するのがとても難しい重要な側面があります。
- 指標は解釈可能であるべきです。 これらの指標の目的は、私たちの努力がどのように変化をもたらしているかを簡単な方法で示すことです：何がうまくいっていてコミュニティがもっと注意を払うべきかが明確になり、 コミュニティ内のプロセスの評価数と改善に必要な行動との関連付けがより容易になります。
- 指標は普遍的であるべきです。 私たちの構想が機能しているのか改善されるべきなのかを理解するために、他のサイトでも同じ指標を見ることができるのは素晴らしいことです。

#### 主な指標: コミュニティ、品質、分量

全体的なコミュニティの状況を把握するために、3つの分野を使って具体的な指標を見ます。:

1. **コミュニティ**: コミュニティでユーザーはどの程度快適に利用できているでしょうか？質問や回答、投票などを通してサイトは活発に利用されていますか？皆さんは同僚を招待したいですか？皆さんの同僚はコミュニティに参加したいと思ってくれるでしょうか？
2. **品質**: 私たちが日本語を話すプログラマ向けに作り上げたナレッジは、どれくらい有益で興味深いものでしょうか？
3. **分量**: 知識ベースはどれくらいの速度で成長していますか？ 知識ベースには必要な質問がありませんか？

#### どのような指標を見たいですか？

あなたが進展を確認するために使用したい指標をコミュニティと共有してください。これらの指標をどのように割り出しますか？それらを測定するためにはどのようなデータを使うべきですか？

混乱を避けるため、**回答毎に1つの指標のみを投稿してください。** 各項目（コミュニティ、品質、分量)に最適な指標を実装し、全員が利用できるようにします。

Answer (score 4):

ひとつ、この日本語版(のみ)で有効な、指標になりうるデータとして、はてなブックマーク数があるかなと思います。

画面
https://b.hatena.ne.jp/entrylist?url=ja.stackoverflow.com

api
https://syncer.jp/hatebu-api-matome

エンジニアの中には、有益なコンテンツを見つけると、はてなブックマークする層が一定数いて、その実、 google の検索エンジンの結果の中で、はてなブックマーク数が多いページにアクセスすると、いい情報が見つかる傾向が、そこそこあると思っています。

なので、各質問投稿ページのはてなブックマーク数、というのは定期収集したら面白い指標になるんじゃなかろうか、と思っています。

Answer (score 2):

コミュニティの良さを測る指標として「一定期間中（たとえば1ヶ月）の新規ユーザーの数」が使えるかもしれません。閲覧するだけならログインしなくても良いので、投稿・投票・通報等をしたくなった程度に良いコミュニティと判断できそうです。

ただ、スパム的な大量作成や、バッジ目当てで他サイトからやってくるユーザーによって多少数字がぶれるかもしれません。

Comment: モデレーター限定で [アクセス分析](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/admin/analytics) のデータを表示することができますが、検索キーワードが文字化けしてたり、アクセス数が不自然に同じ数字になっていたりで若干バグっぽいものを抱えています。

Comment: アクセス数ではなくて、新規ユーザー登録者数のつもりでした。